# Queuing theory. Modification in the M/M/1 model

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process

In a queue of type M/M/1 when making the following modification: when there are 3 customers in the system (2 in the queue and 1 being served) if another one arrives he will leave and never come back. How do I obtain the stationary distribution of the chain? How would you interpret it?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

This is a "blocked customers cleared" queue rather than "blocked customers delayed". Interpret it thus:

$$ i \Rightarrow i+1, 0\leq i\leq2$$
$$ i \Rightarrow i-1, 1\leq i\leq3$$

Then just find and solve the balance equations in the normal way.